# Julia: how to use type

Tags: julia

```
struct MyData
    data
    # constructor
    function MyData()
        data = 1
    end
end

myData = MyData()
myData.data #error
```

I assumed Julia's `struct` was just like `struct` in C. So I don't know why I get an error there:

> type int64 has no field data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions in Julia return the last expression in them. In this case, it is `data = 1`, that is `data` is returned instead of new instance of `MyData`. Simply add line with `new(data)` after `data = 1` to return new instance of `MyData`, and it will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you want to use a so-called "outer constructor", i.e. a function of the same name that is defined *outside* the definition of the type itself. You also want to specify the type of each field as a concrete type, e.g. `Int` in this example:

```
struct MyType
    data::Int
end
```

This has already defined, automatically, a couple of constructors:

```
x = MyType(3)
x.data
```

You can define new outer constructors, e.g. to have a default value:

```
MyType() = MyType(0)  # defines a new constructor

x = MyType()
```

The kind of constructor you were trying to define is called an "inner constructor" (since it lives inside the type definition). It is used when there is something special that you want to force for each new object. For example, you could make sure that the data must be positive and throw and error if not:

```
struct MyType2
    data::Int

    function MyType2(x::Int)
        if x <= 0
            throw(ArgumentError("x must be positive"))
        end

        new(x)
    end
end

x = MyType2(3)
y = MyType2(-17)
```

You should have a look at the documentation on constructors:

http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/constructors/